# Short XML parser

Tags: c#, beginner, parsing, xml

This is my first code in C# ever.  It compiles and works as intended (not complete), but I want to see what I'm doing right and wrong as a first-timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event driven by browsing a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog oOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            oOpenFileDialog.Title = "Open XML File";
            oOpenFileDialog.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
            if (!oOpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists) { MessageBox.Show("Invalid Filename!"); }
            if (IsLinux) { MessageBox.Show("Linux! Not supported!"); }
            else { oOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\...too..long"; }

            if (oOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                buildTree(oOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString());

                PBC pbcXmlData = Deserialize(oOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                Console.Write("Validating.......");
                ValidateXml(oOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("File Path: " + oOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString());
                PrintXmlData(pbcXmlData);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds the treeview of the user's XML file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="szPbcFilePath">XML Filename</param>
        public void buildTree(String szPbcFilePath)
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNode xmlnode;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szPbcFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode;
            tNode = treeView.Nodes[0];
            AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for buildTree() to add nodes to the treeview
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inXmlNode">input XML Node</param>
        /// <param name="inTreeNode">input Tree</param>
        public void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
        {
            XmlNode xNode ;
            TreeNode tNode ;
            XmlNodeList nodeList ;
            int i = 0;
            if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                    tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
                    AddNode(xNode, tNode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// User's PBC.xml is validated against the PBC.xsd schema.
        /// If the PBC is well-formed and valid, writes to console
        /// "Document is valid." Otherwise, it gives an error message.
        /// 
        /// Rules:
        /// 1.) Exactly one PBCVersion, ProjectName, ProjectVersion element
        /// 2.) PBC/Packages/Package/Depedencies/BuildDependency/RelativeSandboxPath element must be unique
        /// 3.) PBC/Targets/Target/TargetName element must be unique
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="szPbcFilePath">User's PBC.xml file path</param>
        public void ValidateXml(String szPbcFilePath)
        {
            XmlSchemaSet oSchemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            oSchemas.Add(null, @"C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\PBC.xsd");

            XDocument oPbcDocument = XDocument.Load(szPbcFilePath);
            string szErrorMessage = "";
            oPbcDocument.Validate(oSchemas, (o, e) =>
            {
                szErrorMessage += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            });
            Console.WriteLine(szErrorMessage == "" ? "Document is valid" : "Document invalid: " + szErrorMessage);
        }

        public static void PrintXmlData(PBC pbcXmlData) {} **IRRELEVANT*

        /// <summary>
        /// User's PBC.xml is deserialized into a PBC object 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="szPbcFilePath">User's PBC.xml file path</param>
        /// <returns>Deserialized PBC.xml of object PBC</returns>
        public static PBC Deserialize(String szPbcFilePath)
        {
            XmlSerializer oXmlDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PBC));
            TextReader oTextReader = new StreamReader(szPbcFilePath);
            object oDeserializerObject = oXmlDeserializer.Deserialize(oTextReader);
            PBC oPbcXmlData = (PBC)oDeserializerObject;
            oTextReader.Close();
            return oPbcXmlData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Detects the execution platform at runtime.
        /// PlatformID 4 = Unix
        /// PlatformID 6 = MacOSX
        /// PlatformID 128 = Unix (.NET 1.0 and 1.1)
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsLinux
        {
            get
            {
                int iPlatformVersion = (int)Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
                return (iPlatformVersion == 4) || (iPlatformVersion == 6) || (iPlatformVersion == 128);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Root Element: <PBC>
    /// Parents: <PBCVersion>, <ProjectName>, <ProjectVersion>,
    ///          <Targets>, <Packages>
    /// Children: <Targets/Target>, <Packages/Package>
    /// </summary>
    [XmlRoot("PBC")]
    public class PBC
    {
        [XmlElement("PBCVersion")]
        public String szPBCVersion;
        [XmlElement("ProjectName")]
        public String szProjectName;
        [XmlElement("ProjectVersion")]
        public String szProjectVersion;
        [XmlArray("Targets")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Target")]
        public List<Target> oTargetList = new List<Target>();
        [XmlArray("Packages")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Package")]
        public List<Package> oPackageList = new List<Package>();
    }

    public class Target : Elements
    {
        [XmlElement("TargetName")]
        public String szTargetName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Package : Elements
    {
        [XmlElement("PackageName")]
        public String szPackageName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Elements
    {
        [XmlElement("CommandLine")]
        public String szCommandLine { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BuildEnvTypeName")]
        public String szBuildEnvTypeName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RelativeOutputPath")]
        public String szRelativeOutputPath { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RelativeLogPath")]
        public String szRelativeLogPath { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("Dependencies")]
        [XmlArrayItem("BuildDependency")]
        public List<BuildDependency> oBuildDependency = new List<BuildDependency>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parents: <ProjectName>, <ProjectVersion>, <TargetName>, 
    ///          <ProjectBuild>, <RelativeSandboxPath>
    /// </summary>
    public class BuildDependency
    {
        [XmlElement("ProjectName")]
        public String szBdProjectName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ProjectVersion")]
        public String szBdProjectVersion { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TargetName")]
        public String szBdTargetName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ProjectBuild")]
        public String szBdProjectBuild { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RelativeSandboxPath")]
        public String szBdRelativeSandboxPath { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't cast an enum to `int` like you're doing in `IsLinux`, you're defeating the purpose of the [PlatformID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration! Instead of having easily readable, self-documenting, strongly-typed identifiers in your code, you've put *magic numbers*!

Comment: Here's a great guide to widely accepted C# naming conventions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What's wrong with LINQ to XML? That code makes me cry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Overall Impression** 
Applications should be split into layers. 
I know it's a simple, throwaway, demo application but these are a perfect opportunity to start working on splitting an application into a Model, View and X. (A Matter Of Personal Preference *(AMOPP)*; looking at the namespaces, you are working with WinForms - I would go with WPF instead. Have a google and see what you think of the arguments)

**Naming** 
Hungarian Notation is **not** recommended for C# code. 
Pascal Naming is recommended for methods (e.g. `BuildTree()` rather than `buildTree()` )(though this may just be a typo as the others are Pascal Cased)
`PBC` is not a useful class name. Something descriptive of the function is better. Similarly `Elements`, is too vague and general.

**Other Things** 
I find

```
if (!oOpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists) { MessageBox.Show("Invalid Filename!"); }
```

puzzling.  It has been a while but, as far a I remember, `CheckFileExists` is a property that one sets before showing the dialog, telling it to display a warning (or not) if the file selected doesn't exist.  The code above is not the correct usage (and will never show the "Invalid FileName!" message because the default is **true**.)

The processing order seems off,  you are deserializing the contents of the file (I'd pass in a stream here, rather than a file name. It gives much more flexibility), then validating it - which, AFAIK, should never run if the Xml is invalid because the deserialization will throw an exception (Haven't tested this so I may be wrong, but either way, validating after a successful load seems off).

Grab the file name out of the open dialog and store it so that you do not have to keep using  `oOpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString()`

Answer (score 4):

- You have an awful lot of code behind your form. I bet this won't be the only place you'll want to prompt a user for a file and display a tree. Put those methods in their own classes for reusability.
- Hungarian notation is not recommended in c#. If you're going to use it, which I recommend against, [variable names should indicate their *kind* instead of their *type*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Really though, just don't use Hungarian notation. Everyone messes it up.
- Take advantage of the fact that c# is case sensitive. `FileStream` is different from `fileStream`, so don't use `fs`. It's over abbreviated.
- There's a file path hardcoded into `ValidateXml`. Use a constant instead. It will be easier to swap out later. The way it is, that function will work *only on your machine*.

Comment: Do you mean “`FileStream` is different from `fileStream`”?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for calling that out @svick.